# how to get rowindex of selected checkbox from datagridview in C# window application

Tags: c#

In my C# application have one datagridview and that contain multiple line of data,also that datagridview contain checkBox for each row.also i provide above datagridview 1 checkBox that name is 'chkselectAll' when we checked that chkSelectAll checkbox then all record of datagridview selected and also when i unchecked one of the record of datagridview then that above chkSelectAll checkbox is unchecked,that functinality is worked but my question is  suppose in my datagridview have 3 record wehen i select all one by one that time how to checked the chkSelectAll checkbox.
Please help me.

Comment: you need to either set a command execution, but this then would cause postback everytime or use JQuery on the clientside and have it do it there instead, which would be better from a UX point of view.

Comment: Is is windows forms or asp?

Comment: window form application

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use a variable as a counter. Increment it when a checkbox is checked and decrement it when it is unchecked, inside DataGridView_CellContentClick event method.

Or, check every time the cell content is clicked that all checkboxes are selected or not inside DataGridView_CellContentClick event method.

Don't forget to put the code inside:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["CheckBoxColumn"].Index)
{
    // use anyone of the above methods here.
}
```